# Как получить данные из devtools в selenium 4 для python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

В интернете пишут про методы execute_cdp_cmd и подобное, но в selenium 4.8.2 нет таких методов, не пойму как зайти во внутрь devtools и смотреть все вкладки и их данные, например список ресурсов в network?

Comment: https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/awesome-chrome-devtools

Comment: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Comment: @nexoma а для firefox есть?

Comment: счас поищем и для firefox

Comment: вот что-то похожее https://github.com/jpramosi/geckordp

Comment: любопытное по хрому https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium

Comment: по firefox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73692117/how-to-send-messages-to-firefox-through-devtools-protocol

Comment: @nexoma как это все относится к selenium?

Comment: это работает ортогонально, selenium отдельно, а devtools отдельно/ ознакомьтесь со стандартом на webdriver и поищите там devtools

Comment: @nexoma про selenium читал документацию и там ни чего толкового про devtools, причем все это говорят, есть же метод find_element который понятно работает с dom, есть функции которые работают с браузером в целом, где функции которые работают с devtools, нет такого((

Comment: потому что devtools отдельный предмет, не имеющий отношения к стандарту webdriver и selenium.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144715/discussion-between--and-nexoma).

Comment: я не работал с devtools программным доступом, увы. тут нечего мне сказать.